# pdflatex with auto-pst-pdf won't compile anymore

Tags: psfrag, auto-pst-pdf

I tried to compile a document with an eps figure in it the same way I used to before. After my update yesterday (first one in ... years...) compilation won't work anymore, even with old eps-figures that used to work (I'm absolutely sure, since I triple checked on this in an old pdf)

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel} 

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

%\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=footnotesize,format=hang,justification=justified,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp] %Positionsangabe
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{BVCyPen.eps}
\end{center}
\caption{Bildbeschreibung
\label{fig:Markierung}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> The error I always get is: "xxx-pics.pdf not found" and the warnings
>   "Creation of xxx-autopp.dvi failed" as well as "Creation of
>   xxx-pics.pdf failed".

And yes, I'm planning on replacing the TMP marks with other text, once compilation works.
I'm using MikTeX x64 and TeXnicCenter

Hopefully you can tell me what causes the problem.

Comment: The update has been announced as an "major" one, so it is possible that something really broke - auto-pst-pdf is a difficult beast (I didn't yet had the time to get it so I can't check). But is is also possible that you simply didn't get everything. Check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388.

Comment: I have no problem with a test eps and up-to-date TeXLive

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... and I solved it... kind of
First you need to aktivate shell escape. 
It worked with me when i took out the `inputenc-package` and used `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}`.
I don't understand LaTeX, I just use it and it worked... Problem is now, that LaTeX doesn accept `ä`,`ö`,`ü` anymore because `inputenc` is no longer used... did not solve that problem yet.